# Coloring edges differently according to group in D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, css, json, d3.js, force-layout

I want to create a force directed graph like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 and I am able to do so using the code provided on the website.

The tweak I want to perform in this is: I wanna color the edges(links) in different colors so as to depict the relationship between two nodes distinctly.

I have my json structure looking like:

```
{
"links": [
    {
        "group": 2,
        "source": "node1",
        "target": "node2",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "group": 1,
        "source": "node2",
        "target": "node3",
        "value": "5"
    }],
"nodes":
[{ "name": "node1" }
 { "name": "node2" }
 { "name": "node3" }]}
```

I tried:

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
```

and for styling it:

```
.style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.group)})
```

with no success. The thing is if I place the color as "red" or "blue" or any other instead of placing the function, all the edges are colored fine. Also, I am able to color the "nodes" differently as given in the sample force directed graph but the same attribute is not getting applicable for the links.

I tried the most naive way of comparing as

```
if (d.group == 1) { return "blue"; }
```

but still with no success. Im clearly missing out something very basic. Can anyone help me out in this. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you link to the full source on blocks or jsfiddle? Your code looks fine to me, I was able to achieve what you wanted to do with more or less the same code: http://bl.ocks.org/nsonnad/5982652

Comment: For coloring links, you need to decide which node the group comes from, e.g. `return color(d.source.group);`.

Comment: @NikhilS Thank you for your code. Your code works because you are working with the value attribute to decide the color. I could do that but that also determines the stroke width of my edges which I do not want to alter.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Thank you for response but can you explain why is the group attribute accessed chained to the source or target(d.source.group) as compared to the value attribute which is accessed just as d.value? Why wont d.group work here?

Comment: Sorry, I misread -- you're representing this explicitly in the JSON. Well in that case it should work really -- did you verify that `d.group` gives you the right value?

Comment: actually it does not. For grouping I have a function that groups the data into 4 different categories (from 1 to 4). In the naive version, I check for all values 1 to 4 and have an else statement. Seems like it always goes to the else clause.

I checked using console.log and it gives undefined. Wonder what's going on there.

Comment: Is it possible that your grouping function is taking place after you call the coloring function on the links? I've reworked my original example to add a `group` value to the links and color based on those, also works fine: http://bl.ocks.org/nsonnad/5982652

Comment: @NikhilS Could you explain a bit clearly what you mean by the grouping function? I have the grouping assigned through my python script that generates the JSON file.